# Chess move validation

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that accepts chess moves, validate them and shows the results.

The program should:

- Check wheter or not a move is valid
- Check if a king is in check or in checkmate
- Process the changes in position of the pieces
- Not procees invalid moves
- Use the format shown below, but format can be changed freely if you want

Input:

- Full input:
  white positions, black positions, starting, target position

  [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,h0],[a6,b6,c6,d6,e6,f6,g6,h6,a7,b7,c7,d7,e7,f7,g7,h7], a1, a2
- Positions in the format a-h/0-7, eg. a0
- Special position for beat pieces, for example XX
- list ordered by starting position(Starting with peasants) contaning positions:
      [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,h0]

Output:

- Full output:
  white positions, black positions, valid, check, checkmate

  [a2,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,h0],[a6,b6,c6,d6,e6,f6,g6,h6,a7,b7,c7,d7,e7,f7,g7,h7], true, none, none
- white and black positions is a list with the same format as the input
- valid is boolean of wheter the move is valid or not
- check is either none, white or black
- checkmate is either none, white or black

Programming languages:

All programming languages are possible, but more "mainstream" languages are preferred.

Score:

The lowest working byte size wins, the win is awarded 10 days after the first valid answer.

Test Cases:

```
Input: [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,h0],[a6,b6,c6,d6,e6,f6,g6,h6,a7,b7,c7,d7,e7,f7,g7,h7], a1, a2
Output: [a2,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,h0],[a6,b6,c6,d6,e6,f6,g6,h6,a7,b7,c7,d7,e7,f7,g7,h7], true, none, none

Input: [a5,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,h0],[a6,b6,c6,d6,e6,f6,g2,h6,a7,b7,c7,d7,e7,f7,g7,h7], a5, b6
Output: [b6,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,a0,b0,c0,d0,e0,f0,g0,h0],[a6,xx,c6,d6,e6,f6,g2,h6,a7,b7,c7,d7,e7,f7,g7,h7], true, none, none

Input: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,d0,xx,xx,xx,h0],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,e7,xx,xx,xx], h0, h7
Output: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,d0,xx,xx,xx,h7],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,e7,xx,xx,xx], true, black, none

Input: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,d0,xx,xx,xx,h0],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,e7,xx,xx,xx], h0, h6
Output: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,d0,xx,xx,xx,h0],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,e7,xx,xx,xx], false, none, none

Input: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,d0,xx,xx,xx,h0],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,e7,xx,xx,xx], h0, h8
Output: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,d0,xx,xx,xx,h0],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,e7,xx,xx,xx], false, none, none

Input: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,f4,xx,xx,xx,a0],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,h4,xx,xx,xx], a0, h0 
Output: [xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,d0,xx,xx,xx,h0],[xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,e7,xx,xx,xx], true, none, black
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it a valid chess move?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/148587/38592)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first challenge. Don't let its closure discourage you from participating here but, for future challenges, you might consider using [our Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where dupes and other potential issues will often be caught before a challenge can be posted to Main.